# SQL: Comparing multiple dates

Tags: sql-server-2008, select

I got a table with multiple columns that contain DateTime namely `gendate1` up to `gendate8`. In my stored procedure, the user will have to input a date (`@date_start`). Now I have to compare the inputted date to the 8 dates which will filter all the data. The problem is that I have to get the two closest dates (out of eight dates) to the given date. Sorry I'm just a beginner in sql.

**In response to sir Akina**

I don't have the actual code yet because it confuses me of what to do first.

1. Should I make a temporary table, loop the result of the query and filter each of the result (but how to get the 2 closest dates out of eight dates) then insert it to the temporary table?
2. or should I put all the condition under the `where` clause?

**Example**

```
 gendate1 = '1/6/2019'
,gendate2 = '4/6/2019'
,gendate3 = '2/6/2019'
,gendate4 = '3/6/2019'
,gendate5 = '5/6/2019'
,gendate6 = '7/6/2019'
,gendate7 = '8/6/2019'
,gendate8 = '10/6/2019'

@date_start = '1/30/2019'
```

How to get the `gendate1` and `gendate3`? (they are the closest to `@date_start`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with 

cte1 as (
    select id, 1 num, gendate1 gendate from test union all
    select id, 2 num, gendate2 gendate from test union all
    select id, 3 num, gendate3 gendate from test union all
    select id, 4 num, gendate4 gendate from test union all
    select id, 5 num, gendate5 gendate from test union all
    select id, 6 num, gendate6 gendate from test union all
    select id, 7 num, gendate7 gendate from test union all
    select id, 8 num, gendate8 gendate from test 
),

cte2 as (
    select id, num, gendate, row_number() over (partition by id order by gendate desc) rn
    from cte1
    where gendate <= '1/30/2019'
union all
    select id, num, gendate, row_number() over (partition by id order by gendate asc) rn
    from cte1
    where gendate >= '1/30/2019'
)

select id, num, gendate
from cte2
where rn = 1
order by id, gendate
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e233aaf670ebfe4850c797e09612ea3b)

If there are duplicated dates in `gendateX` fields within the row, the `num` returned will be random. To avoid use RANK() instead of ROW_NUMBER() and use

```
select id, MAX(num) num, gendate -- or MIN()
from cte2
where rnk = 1
group by id, gendate
order by id, gendate
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ccfdff047ae11f0163d9002517a757f4)

Answer (score 3):

A slightly different and much more efficient approach (single CIX scan instead of [SIXTEEN CIX scans](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNwGh.png)). Assuming this table:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.tablename
(
  id int PRIMARY KEY,
  gendate1 datetime,  gendate2 datetime,  gendate3 datetime,  gendate4 datetime,
  gendate5 datetime,  gendate6 datetime,  gendate7 datetime,  gendate8 datetime
);
```

Then we can use this query to unpivot:

```
DECLARE @date_start datetime = '20190130';

;WITH x AS
(
  SELECT tp.id, tp.d FROM dbo.tablename AS t
  UNPIVOT 
  (
    d FOR ds IN 
    (
      t.gendate1,t.gendate2,t.gendate3,t.gendate4,
      t.gendate5,t.gendate6,t.gendate7,t.gendate8
    )
  ) AS tp
)
SELECT id, 
  next_date = MIN(CASE WHEN d > @date_start THEN d END),
  prev_date = MAX(CASE WHEN d < @date_start THEN d END)
FROM x
GROUP BY id;
```

If you want a tie when `@date_start` is a direct hit, pick one to change to `>=` or `<=` (just don't do that to both).

Results with a single id given the sample data in the question:

> [image]

Plan here is much nicer:

> [image]